# How can we not give into cultural misinformation?

Tags: discussion

So I recently posted this question:

[Looking at quantum physics from the perspective of Indian philosophy?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/102018/looking-at-quantum-physics-from-the-perspective-of-indian-philosophy)

And got quite upset when the answerer makes claims like: "There's no evidence that Hindu mathematicians developed even a rudimentary theory of (mathematical) probability"

See: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/B978044451862050037X

Coming from a background of colonisation where there was an active attempt to erase and downplay our heritage I'd like to ask how should I proceed to ensure these misgivings do not find their place atleast on this site.

Comment: An [old question](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/16131/37256) ... much rarer nowadays unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

Tricky one this one.  Because of the language of this site, there is quite a lot of anglocentricism - other philosophical traditions need English language advocates in order to have an impact in anglophonic scholarly cultures.

A key motivating factor in present reinvigoration of philosophical traditions of other languages is exactly their independence from hegemonic English traditions, *because* the English tradition has historically not been very welcome to alternative foundations.

I think your respondent is basically saying “well nobody told us”.  A natural rejoinder is “we did, you just weren’t listening”, but sadly to the current generation of anglophonic philosophers, this is *active research* rather than history exactly because of the historic intransigence of past scholars.

So I think you’re right, but you have to situate this in a deeply problematic philosophical culture; in that context, there is probably not a lot of existing support for the positions you’re looking for.